# php:配列内の要素と一致する要素があるかどうかの判定

Tags: php

PHPで配列内の要素と一致する要素があるかどうかの判定はどのような書き方があるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_searchかin_array

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;

$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```